# Why is there a question with the non-descriptive title *Function "Love Triangle"*?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, titles

When asking a question the title text-box has the instruction
[image: What's your math question? Be specfic.]
and there are some guidelines on how to write a good title in the [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144) meta-thread.

In my mind [Function “Love Triangle”](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2354094/1)
 is one of the atrociously bad titles because it does not tell anything about the question being asked. I wouldn't very far-fetched to say that this clickbait title was selected to get HNQ rep. Needless to say, I was very disappointed to find out that there is nothing about "love" in the question rather it was about boring function compositions.

Why this title is still up? Is this a valid title?

Comment: I was going to bring something like this up myself when I noticed the related questions to [2 problems in combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2355276/437127). You'd think at some point people would run out of variations on "a problem in combinatorics".

Comment: Thanks for posting this, though I'm a bit late in the "game".  The title you point out is what is known as click-bait.  Only yesterday, (Friday/14th) the post was tweeted,  and as you point out, became a HNQ. Hence it's high (excessive) votes, and hence the excessive votes of the answers.  The asker has rolled back all title edits in order to reinstate their original title, which you note. I tried to edit it within the last half-hour of my comment here.  Hope it sticks.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you very much for for edit. I wouldn't have noticed that he rollbacked both the edits.

Comment: No problem, @A--B.  Both arjafi and Daniel Fischer edited the title;  I came upon your question fairly late, checked the link you gave, and saw that the asker had rolled back both mods' edits.  Checked again just now, and my edit, so far,  seems to be "sticking".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The title *was* still up because none of the 4000+ people who had viewed that question bothered to edit the title. Of course, not all of those 4000+ people have accounts on Mathematics Stack Exchange, and while anonymous suggested edits are a thing, we shouldn't rely on passers-by to tidy up the site. That 4000+ number also includes numerous users with the 2000-reputation [Edit Questions And Answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege who could have edited it without even creating review tasks for others.

Instead of complaining about an poor title, it would be more productive and helpful to just jump in there and [make a change](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2354094/4).

Comment: Maybe to link to revisions page rather than the exact revision is better as for the latter the change of the title is hardly noticeable. Then there are also drawbacks, hence I did not do it and leave it up to you.

Comment: Note that the asker has repeatedly rolled back efforts to edit the title.

Comment: All attempted edits of the title, including your edit, and @Daniel Fischer's edit, have been rolled back by the asker, nonetheless.  I've just tried to edit the title again; whether it sticks, is yet to be seen.